# How would I get and filter info that's printed in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

If the terminal printed(echoed) a bunch of strings like:

```
aPath
aSecondPath
aThirdPath
```

How would I filter through these and find the `ThirdPath` for example?

Comment: Read SO [MCVE] and try to improve your question.

Comment: Also read [ask].

Comment: I'd have supposed this Q. is a duplicate, but couldn't seem to find a matching Q. that's quite this basic.

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU* `grep`:

```
printf '%s\n' aPath aSecondPath aThirdPath | grep -o ThirdPath
```

Leave out the `-o` to print the whole line "***a****ThirdPath*".